# Clear float not adding space between next paragraph

Tags: css, css-float

I used a float, however after `<div style="clear: both;"></div>`the next paragraph is immediately after the content above, at least that is the case on Safari, Chrome, and Firefox. I do not have IE to check what is happening there.

Here is the code:

```
<div style="float: left;">
<div style="clear: both; padding-left: 30px;"><span style="color: #e05900;"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"><span style="display: none;">icon-chevron-circle-right</span></i> </span>I am afraid of...</div>
<div style="clear: both; padding-left: 30px;"><span style="color: #e05900;"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"><span style="display: none;">icon-chevron-circle-right</span></i> </span>I will wait until…</div>
<div style="clear: both; padding-left: 30px;"><span style="color: #e05900;"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"><span style="display: none;">icon-chevron-circle-right</span></i> </span>I don’t have enough experience to…</div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
That is mind chatter
```

There is no break between That is mind chatter and the line proceeding it, I don’t have enough experience to…

Comment: Why should there be any additional space? You haven't declared any vertical margins or padding between each element, and you haven't used any elements with default margins such as `p` - the part that says "That is mind chatter" is bare text.

Comment: That is what I do not understand, hence why I posted the question.